# Remove Old NTAuth CA

Tags: windows, certificate

I can see 2 CA certificates with this command.

Certificate preview

[image: 1]

*certutil.exe -enterprise -viewstore NTAuth*

These are remnants of the CA that was uninstalled.

Is it safe to delete it ? If yes, how do I delete it?

I only see the registry keys

Registry preview

[image: 2]

but I can't find them in the certificate mmc.

Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer to myself if it help someone.
In an admin's shell, launch these 2 commands:

```
certutil -viewdelstore " ldap:///CN=NtAuthCertificates,CN=Public Key
Services,...,DC=ForestRoot,DC=com?cACertificate?base?objectclass=certificationAuthority"

certutil -viewdelstore " ldap:///CN=NtAuthCertificates,CN=Public Key
Services,...,DC=ForestRoot,DC=com?cACertificate?base?objectclass=pKIEnrollmentService"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).